# Spring data jpa + hibernate deleteInBatch call fires 3 sql statements for composite key enstance

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

by performing call to reporitory deleteInBatch with collection of one object which is essentially linking table record, i can see in hibernate logs following:

delete __    from__        composite_key_linking_table __    where__        first_entity_id=?

update__        composite_key_linking_table __    set__        first_entity_id=null __    where__        first_entity_id=?

delete __    from__        result_qt_code __    where__        second_entity_id=? __        and first_entity_id=? __        and composite_key_third_part=?

i believe last sql query causes

```
org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1;
```

Before delete call i have removed the instance from its owner instance.

Need help.